# Django import error when apps with same name

Tags: python, django, import, importerror

The structure of my django project is:

```
project
    book (an app)
        __init__.py
        views.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        ...
    api (an app)
        __init__.py
        problem.py
        book (another app for REST API)
            __init__.py
            views.py
            urls.py
            ...
```

When I try to " from book.models import * " in api/problem.py, django said "ImportError: No module named models". I think that is because it try to import "api/book/models.py" which does not exist. How can I do to import modules from root folder? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `import *`, it can create conflicts. Imports only what you need. First make sure `__init__` exists for each folder that you are going to need to import. You don't need a seperate app for `api`. Just make `api.py` in `book` (and every other app you intend to make that requires to have public apis.

Comment: Actually I am quite confused. Which `models` do you want to import from? The first `book`'s models.py or `api/book/<models.py>` ? If the latter case, yes you definitely is missing models. But if you can't import from the first case, then make sure `__init__` is there and try to import from `project.book.models import some_class` as you observed it's trying to import the local book version.

Comment: It's the first case. There is an __init__.py in project/book/, and I can " from book.models import * " when I use " python manage.py shell ", but not in project/api/problem.py. Still need helps, thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your post and tell us all the necessary files (include `__init__.py`? I find it strange `from project.book.models import some_class` doesn't work.

Comment: OK. There is no __init__.py in project folder.

Comment: Try put the init file under project folder? And do what the import i tell you to try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are extremely desperate, you can try this.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
model_ct = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="book", model="some_model_you_gonna_import")
target_model = model_ct.model_class()
```

By doing so, you are able to get class you might need.
(using target_model as the one you are going to import)

BTW, I've tried this. should work. :p

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to sanitize the project structure so that `api.book` was `book.api` instead.

E.g, structure your project as:

```
project
    book (an app)
        views.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        api (another app for REST API)
            views.py
            urls.py
            ...
        ...
    api (an app)
        __init__.py
        problem.py
        ...
```

Comment: Did you mean that you have api folder in every apps?

Comment: Yes, but no. I'll revise the answer to explain

Answer (score 0):

You could try relative import, refs [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)

```
# in api.problem.py
from ..book.models import something
```

This style is unrecommended but it helps if refactoring package structures and names is difficulty.

Comment: Still got No module named book.models

Comment: What's your sys.path look like? Did you get this in shell instead of in `manage.py run`?